# Como pegar o size da imagem com o Cordova?

Tags: apache-cordova

Tenho a seguinte função, e preciso pegar o *size* da imagem para validar, pois não é permitido subir uma imagem maior que um determinado tamanho.
Não consigo pegar com JS normal porque não uso um `FileUplod`, e sim pelo `navigator.camera.getPicture`. Tentei usar as funções relatadas na documentação mas não consegui encaixá-la com o código já existente. Não sei se tem como pegar o *size* dessa forma que pego a imagem usando o `getPicture`

```js
function PerfilEscolherFoto() {
    var srcType = Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM;
    var options = {
        // Some common settings are 20, 50, and 100
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        // In this app, dynamically set the picture source, Camera or photo gallery
        sourceType: srcType,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        allowEdit: true,
        correctOrientation: true  //Corrects Android orientation quirks
    }
    navigator.camera.getPicture(function cameraSuccess(imageUri) {
        onSuccess1(imageUri);console.log(imageUri)
    }, function cameraError(error) {
        onFail1();
    }, options);

    function onSuccess1(imageData) {
        
        if (imageData.indexOf("?")=="-1"){
            imageData3 = imageData;

        } else {
            imageData2 = imageData.split('?');
            imageData3 = imageData2[0];
        }

        $(".FotoEditarAtleta").css("background", "url('"+ imageData3 +"?"+ Math.random() +"') no-repeat center").css('background-size', 'contain').css({ transform : 'rotate(0deg)' });
        $("#foto").val(imageData3);
    }

    function onFail1(message) {
        //alert('Erro ao selecionar imagem, tente novamente');
    }
}
```

Comment: Vê se essa resposta do SOEn pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11999301/2570426